# Is it possible for the server to "listen in" to an audio or video stream?

Tags: webrtc, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Using agora.io I'd like to do something like realtime subtitles for video meetings.
Is there a way to have a **server** get at the data of the video/audio streams?

The server [REST api](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/rtc_restful_api) seems very basic just for project management.

I want to get at the streaming audio data, not a [local client capture like this demo](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Audio/tree/dev/backup/Pronunciation-Assess/Pronunciation-Assess-Android)

Perhaps I could use something like the [cloud proxy](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/cloudproxy_native?platform=Android) although I would need to "T Pipe" the data, and I assume the data would be encrypted, not sure if the keys used are something I can get access to.

It also seems like the [web client](https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/browser_support) has browser dependencies; perhaps I could run that on a headless/chrome node server, but that seems like a hack and very resource intensive.

Any other suggestions on places I can look for APIs?

Also interested in other webrtc APIs and provider alternatives. Maybe Twilio has some APIs for this.

Comment: twilio has https://www.twilio.com/media-streams but its for their voice stuff, not their video stuff (yet)

Answer (score 0):

We provide Linux SDK on a case by case basis which you can deploy headless in your server. This SDK itself will act as a client that joins the channel and receives the video streams in the channel.

The SDK is written in c++ and is not public. you can request access by opening a support ticket at https://agora-ticket.agora.io/